# MVVM Light DialogMessage

Tags: mvvm-light

im trying to use the mvvmlight DialogMessage.

```
var message = new DialogMessage(
            "Confirm Delete", RemoveAddressAction)
            { 
                Button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, 
                Caption = "Caption??" 
            };
```

VS2010 undelines the "Button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel" line complaining about

"Cannot convert source type 'System.Windows.MessageBoxButton [PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture...] to target type 'System.Windows.MessageBoxItem [GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=3.0.0.29216, ...]

And a similar issue on the code behind on the view when I try to use the DialogMessage to show the messagebox.

Has anyone encountered this before? I have no clue how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I removed the refrences to GalaSoft.MvvmLight, added them again, and rebuilding resolved the compiler errors.

Cleaning and rebuilding the solution did not work, until removed and readded the references.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code in mine (VS2010) and it builds with no underline.  Things to try: 
Solution Clean and Build; Check if you have the latest of MVVM Light;
Check Button's type and explicitly state System.Windows.MessageBoxButton or System.Windows.MessageBoxItem;  Target .NET 4.0..?;

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I'm pretty sure I tried all of those shortly after posting. It definitely works with net3.5.  Anyway I re-tried it after some time and the issue disappeared. I dont know what I did, maybe I rebooted or something. This is the most frustrating kind of issue, because there is no apparent fix or solution. It just went away when I tried again.